# Whats the better approach to do this in c#?

Tags: c#, math

I am trying to do something:

```
  Input  <=  3432

  Output =>  List contains 7 items i.e. (3, 1000, 4, 100, 3, 10, 2)
```

For this i write a function in c#:

```
public BigInterger FromDecimal()
{
    List<BigInteger> numbers = new List<BigInteger>();

    BigInteger number = BigInteger.Parse(NumberString);

    while (number > 0)
    {
        if (number >= 1000000000)
        {
            numbers.Add(number / 1000000000);
            number = number % 1000000000;
            numbers.Add(1000000000);
        }
        else if (number >= 100000000)
        {
            numbers.Add(number / 100000000);
            number = number % 100000000;
            numbers.Add(100000000);
        }
        else if (number >= 10000000)
        {
            numbers.Add(number / 10000000);
            number = number % 10000000;
            numbers.Add(10000000);
        }
        else if (number >= 1000000)
        {
            numbers.Add(number / 1000000);
            number = number % 1000000;
            numbers.Add(1000000);
        }
        else if (number >= 100000)
        {
            numbers.Add(number / 100000);
            number = number % 100000;
            numbers.Add(100000);
        }
        else if (number >= 10000)
        {
            numbers.Add(number / 10000);
            number = number % 10000;
            numbers.Add(10000);
        }
        else if (number >= 1000)
        {
            numbers.Add(number / 1000);
            number = number % 1000;
            numbers.Add(1000);
        }
        else if (number >= 100)
        {
            numbers.Add(number / 100);
            number = number % 100;
            numbers.Add(100);
        }
        else if (number >= 10)
        {
            numbers.Add(number / 10);
            number = number % 10;
            numbers.Add(10);
        }
        else
        {
            numbers.Add(number);
            number = 0;
        }
    }

    return numbers;
}
```

Now i feel that this code is too bigger, so is there any better approach to achieve this ?

Comment: One better approach that immediately jumps to mind is to add a 1 to your list.  Be consistent - you have multiplier times units pairs for each one, keep it that way to the end.  When you do, you'll find it easier to make a loop.  Or even better, don't list the units at all.  Use 0s when necessary, and then just use some modulo arithmetic.

Comment: Best way is **Recursion**

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code that is working as is, without error. For critique or suggestions on improving your code, please ask on   http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a table of powers of ten, or compute them as you go. This would let you split the number into pairs of digits and their place values using a regular loop, as opposed to using an unrolled loop that goes up to a fixed number.

Here is one way you can do it:

```
var ten = new BigInteger(10);
var res = new List<BigInteger>();
var number = BigInteger.Parse(NumberString);
int pow = 0;
while (!BigInteger.Zero.Equals(number)) {
    var lastDigit = BigInteger.Remainder(number, ten);
    var placeValue = BigInteger.Pow(ten, pow++);
    res.Add(placeValue);
    res.Add(lastDigit);
    number = BigInteger.Divide(number, ten);
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply, can you please give me a sample code for this ?

Comment: @user1740381 This should work - I have not tried it, but it should be simple enough to do the trick. Note that this code produces the output in reverse order, and adds `1` for the place value of the last digit.

Answer (score 0):

```
public List<int> ParseIntoList(string initialNumber, List<int> currentArray)
{
   if (initialNumber.Length == 0){
         return currentArray;
   } 

   var digit = initialNumber[0];
   initialNumber = initialNumber.Substring(1);
   var power = Math.Pow(10, initialNumber.Length);
   currentArray.Add(digit);
   currentArray.Add(power);
   return ParseIntoList(initialNumber, currentArray);
}
```

Call it in the next way: `ParseIntoList("3432", new List <int>()).`
You might want to wrap it in a call or do an itterative version of the algorithm

Answer (score 0):

You can just operate on the strings:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var input = "3432";
    var result = Foo(input);
}

private static string[] Foo(string input)
{
    var output = new List<string>();
    var power = input.Length;

    for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
    {
        output.Add(input[i].ToString());
        if (i < input.Length-1)
            output.Add(Math.Pow(10, power).ToString());

        power--;
    }

    return output.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Reversing twice? Seems unnecessary

Comment: @YuriiHohan you are correct, that is just how I thought through the problem. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

LINQ one liners to rescue!

```
string inputString = "3432";
var result = Enumerable.Range(0, inputString.Length)
                     .SelectMany(
                           i => new[]
                                {
                                   Convert.ToInt32(inputString[i] - '0'),
                                   (int) Math.Pow(10, inputString.Length - i - 1)
                                }, (i, g) => g).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    static IEnumerable<long> GetDigitsAndMultiplesOfTen(long value)
    {
        var powerOfTen = (long)Math.Ceiling(Math.Log10(value));
        var divisor = (long)Math.Pow(10, powerOfTen);

        while (divisor > 0)
        {
            var quotient = value / divisor;

            if (quotient > 0)
            {
                yield return quotient;

                if (divisor > 1)
                    yield return divisor;
            }

            value %= divisor;
            divisor /= 10;
        }
    }
```

Program code:

```
       long value = 3432;

        var list = GetDigitsAndMultiplesOfTen(value).ToList();

        foreach (var item in list)
            Console.WriteLine(item);
```

Output:

```
3
1000
4
100
3
10
2
```